# Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Sidebar>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I was trying to upgrade my angular app from v4 to v9 while i faced this error:

*Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'*

The error occurs here (mock-sidebar.service.ts)

```
return ObservableCreator.createFromData(SIDEBAR)
```

mock-sidebar.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ObservableCreator } from '../pages/common/observable/observable-creator';
import { Sidebar } from '../entities/sidebar';
import { SIDEBAR } from '../mocks/sidebar-mocks';

@Injectable()
export class SidebarService {
    getSidebar(): Observable<Sidebar> {
        return ObservableCreator.createFromData(SIDEBAR);
    }
}
```

observable-creator.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class ObservableCreator {
    public static createFromData(data: any) {
        const observable = new Observable((observer: any) => {
            observer.next(data);
            observer.complete();
        });
        return observable;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use generics for your createFromData function to specify which kind of Observable it should return. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: can you try new Observable<Sidebar>((observer: any) => {
            observer.next(data);
            observer.complete();
        })

Comment: Thank you, it works!
const observable = new Observable<any>((observer: any)

Comment: Your `createFromData` function can simply be replaced with [of](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of)

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix your problem:

```
public static createFromData(data: any) {
    return of(data);
}
```

Another way to fix your problem using generics:

```
public static createFromData<T>(data: T): Observable<T> {
  return new Observable<T>(observer => {
    observer.next(data);
    observer.complete();
  });
}
```

Comment: Note; the problem is not related to [rxjs] but to the type system